# Определить порядок кнопки в ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Есть форма вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка (упрощена для читабельности):

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding FilesCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Button Command="{Binding DeleteFileCommand}">
                </Button>

                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

`FilesCollection` это список `ObservableCollection<AttachmentFileViewModel>`.

Класс `AttachmentFileViewModel`:

```
public class AttachmentFileViewModel
{
    public string FileGuid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Для правильной работы команды удаления нужно получить `FileGuid` удаляемой записи.

Итак вопрос: как можно определить, на какую кнопку я тыкаю? Сейчас, при нажатии я получаю `NullReferenceException`, что в принципе и понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Button Command="{Binding DeleteFileCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

Команда получит в параметре экземпляр `AttachmentFileViewModel`, к которому относится кнопка

Comment: То еще нужно добавить параметр с типом AttachmentFileViewModel в команду?

Comment: Это зависит от вашей реализации `ICommand`, но да — делаете команду с параметром этого типа, либо используете приведение типов, если у вас команда принимает `object`. В моем случае это будет выглядеть примерно так: `DeleteFileCommand = new DelegateCommand(o => FilesCollection.Remove((AttachmentFileViewModel)o)`

Comment: Всё, сделал, спасибо!